# Node-Red: How to stop nodes processing too quickly?

Tags: node-red

I am currently working on creating a Dashboard in MS Excel, using Node-RED to get the data from the source system. In order not to have to import all the gathered data all the time, I created a flow that checks for a file (specifically "ImportSuccess.csv") to be existent using "node-red-contrib-fs-ops 1.6.0", specifically fs-ops-access.

If no, then the message will head into a Join-Node and will be appended to an array.

If yes, then the ImportSuccess.csv should be deleted, the message triggering this will get the "msg.complete" attribute and will be passed into the aforementioned Join-Node and trigger it to send out the whole array into a csv-file, overwriting its previous contents. In Excel, I then get the data from that csv-file and create a new "ImportSuccess.csv" to communicate to Node-RED that my tool is ready for a new batch of data.

Following problem occurs: Due to checking for existence and deleting the file being two different steps, a second message can successfully pass through the existence-check which results in double overwriting of the storage csv-file which causes loss of data.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

#### Flow diagram:

[image: Part of the used flow]

From my understanding, I need to "force" that the upper branch is fully finished before a next message gets to pass through the "File Access"-Node.

Comment: What about checking the file attributes to see if it's been updated before deleting

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more in detail? I am fairly new to Node-RED. The loop works as follows : Excel creates ImportSuccess.csv -> Node-RED finds it, deletes it and posts collected messages into a temporary csv file, overwriting previous content -> excel imports new content and creates new ImportSuccess.csv. How may checking the file attributes help with preventing two messages to go through the upper branch due to the asynchronous flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution by programming my own function node - ty for checking in

EDIT: How to solve the problem by using a Function Node

1. Edit Settings.js with fs: require("fs") under functionGlobalContext
2. Write Function Node as follows:

```
var fs = global.get("fs");
var path = "Your Path";

if fs.existsSync(path){
    >Add attribute "complete" to msg for the Join Node to detect and trigger sending
    msg.complete = Boolean(1);
   
   >Delete File
   fs.unlinkSync(path);
}

return msg;
```

Comment: Please, if you find a solution post here the answer for who has the same problem

Comment: Done - feel free to correct if there are syntax errors, had to write from memory